# Spider Solitaire - Minimum Guaranteed Turnovers

Tags: cards

Consider the following game-state in Spider Solitaire. Although this game is not the most popular compared to others
(e.g. poker, chess, backgammon etc) I assume the reader is familiar with the basic ruleset which is easily found online.
I assume Joe Bloggs is playing at the four-suit level and is not allowed to undo moves.

(1) How many face-down cards is Joe guaranteed to turn over before being forced to deal another row of 10 cards, even if
the worst possible cards turned up?

(2) How many face-down cards can Joe turn over if every face-down card is a cow? Cows can only move to empty columns and
nothing can move onto a cow.

(3) Your answers to (1) and (2) should be the same. Can you construct a game state where they are different? To discourage
trivial solutions let us say the "best" example is one with highest number of unknown cards (either face-down in the tableau or
in the stock).

[image]